# Java - Program to find longest increasing sequence of consecutive elements (logical errors)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am currently creating a program where the user inputs an array of integers. The program has to find the longest increasing sequence of consecutive elements. So if the user enters "3,2,1,2,4,6,7,8,1,2" the program will output "1,2,4,5,6,7,8". However, I keep running into 2 errors.

The first error is that when xs =  1000,97777,487,8274,972837. The program will output "1000,97777" instead of "487,8274,972837". Logically this is wrong since the first output is not the "LONGEST" increasing sequence of consecutive element.

The second error is that when xs = 2,7. It seems to output an empty array instead of "2,7". I'm assuming it's because there aren't enough elements perhaps?

```
    static int[] increasing(int[] xs){
    ArrayList<Integer> current_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();        
    int c_counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<(xs.length); i++){
        if (i==0){
            if (xs[i+1] > xs[i]){
                current_array.add(xs[i]);
                c_counter++; //keeps track of how many elements have been added
            }
        }
        else if ((xs[i] > xs[i-1])){
            if (c_counter==0){
                current_array.add(xs[i-1]); //makes sure the smaller number gets added too
                current_array.add(xs[i]);
                c_counter = c_counter + 2;                    
            } else{
                current_array.add(xs[i]);
                c_counter++;
            }
        } else {
            if (current_array.size()>list.size()){ //compares sizes to find the longest sequence
                list.clear();
                for (int k=0; k<(current_array.size()); k++){
                    if (current_array.get(k) != 0){ //removes any null values
                        list.add(current_array.get(k));
                    }
                }
                current_array.clear(); //clears it to restart and find any longer sequences
                c_counter = 0;                    
            }
        }
    }
    int[] out_array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray(); //converts from arraylist to int[] as that's the format it must output
    out_array = list.stream().filter(i->i != null).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    return out_array;
}
```

Comment: You should rethink your strategy. At any point of time you only need to store a start position and the length of current longest sequence. As you progress through the sequence once the increasing progression ends compare it with the earlier longest sequence (initialised as 0 [position], 0[length]). If you current sequence is longer then store that as your longest sequence details...

Comment: I have understood what you're saying and got rid of the "c_counter" variable. This time I tested the code with the following input: 1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5. This time it outputs "1,2,3" so it seems to be able to compare lengths of sequences, it just won't compare the last sequence. Any idea why?

Comment: Hint: as you and others already figured: your code is overly complex. You want to read about the "single layer of abstraction" principle. And maybe "clean code" by robert martin, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes too long time to understand your code. Try this out:

```
    List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    test.add(3);
    test.add(2);
    test.add(1);
    test.add(2);
//  test.add(4);
//  test.add(6);
//  test.add(7);
//  test.add(8);
    test.add(1);
    test.add(2);        
    test.add(1000);
    test.add(97777);
    test.add(487);
    test.add(8274);
    test.add(972837);
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        int current = test.get(i);          
        int next = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if(i + 1 < test.size()) next = test.get(i + 1);
        if(current > next) {
            if(output.size() <= temp.size()) {
                temp.add(current);
                output = new ArrayList<Integer>(temp);
            }
            temp.clear();
        } else {
            temp.add(current);      
        }
    }       
    output.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + ", "));
```

If you want the longest decreasing output, change `int next = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` and `if(current > next)` to `if(current < next)`

Comment: This seems to work better, thank you so much! I cannot thank you enough. Out of curiosity, what was the issue with my program that yours doesn't have?

Comment: Honestly, I just have a tendency to overcomplicate things. I'll look over it clearly tomorrow and hopefully find out why it sucked lol. A million thanks again, you saved me from failing an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int[] increasing(int[] xs){       
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int temp = 0;       
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        if(i==0 || xs[i]<xs[i-1]){
            temp = i;           
        }
        else if(i-temp > end-start){
            start = temp;
            end = i;
        }
    }
 return Arrays.copyOfRange(xs, start, end+1);       
}
```